# What is a diverging implicit expansion error?

Tags: scala, implicits

While trying to find a solution to another question ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876079/how-can-collections-use-implicit-conversions-on-element-types/4876717#4876717)) I came across a diverging implicit expansion error. I'm looking for an explanation about what this means

Here's the use case:

```
scala> implicit def ordering[T](implicit conv: T => Ordered[T], res: Ordering[Ordered[T]]) = Ordering.by(conv)
ordering: [T](implicit conv: (T) => Ordered[T],implicit res: Ordering[Ordered[T]])scala.math.Ordering[T]

scala> def foo[T <% Ordered[T]](s : Seq[T]) = s.sorted
<console>:6: error: diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[T]
starting with method ordering in object $iw
       def foo[T <% Ordered[T]](s : Seq[T]) = s.sorted
                                                ^
```

Comment: I solved this error in a very different context, which might help someone else. The following did not work in my case: `val seq: Seq[Int] = in.readData()` but by helping the type inferencer by explicitly stating the type parameters of the method, then it worked: `val seq = in.readData[Seq[Int]]()`. However, stating type parameters of `sorted` does not seem to help here for the OT.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you run this in scala with the `-Xlog-implicits` argument passed, you get more information:

> scala.this.Prefed.conforms is not a valid implicit value for (T) => Ordered[T] because:
>
> type mismatch:
>
> found : <:<[T,T]
>
> required: (T) => Ordered[T]
>
> scala.this.predef.conforms is not a valid implicit value for (Ordered[T]) => Ordered[Ordered[T]] because:
>
> type mismatch:
>
> found : <:<[Ordered[T], Ordered[T]]
>
> required : (Ordered[T]) => Ordered[Ordered[T]]
>
> math.this.Ordering.ordered is not a valid implicit value for Ordering[T] because:
>
> type arguments [T] do not conform to method ordered's type parameter bounds [A <: scala.math.Ordered[A]]

This is mostly speculation, but would seem to make some sense. I will try to investigate further:

This seems to suggest that there are three implicits that are being considered here. Ultimately, the signature of `sorted` requires it to find something of type `Ordering[T]`. So it's trying to construct your implicit function `ordering`. Firstly, it's trying to fill in `conv` by finding an implicit of type `(T) => Ordered[T]`, where it's searching in Predef - which seems like barking up the wrong tree. It's then trying to find an implicit for `(Ordered[T]) => Ordered[Ordered[T]]` in the same place, since `by` takes an implicit parameter of type `Ordering[S]`, where `S` is `Ordered[T]` by virtue of `conv`. So it can't construct `ordering`.

It then tries to use `ordering` in math.Ordering, but this also doesn't fit. However, I think this is what's giving the somewhat confusing 'diverging implicits' message. The problem isn't that they're diverging, it's that there isn't a suitable one in scope, but it's being confused by the fact that there are two paths to go down. If one tries to define `def foo[T <% Ordered[T]](s : Seq[T]) = s.sorted` without the implicit ordered function, then it fails with just a nice message saying that it can't find a suitable implicit.

Comment: I don't know, I thought it means that there's recursion. "Two paths to go down" would be "ambiguous implicits" IIUC.