# Why am I getting an error on this simple Scala code?

Tags: scala

Here's my code:

```
object Triple {
  object Num extends Enumeration {
    type Num = Value
    val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
  }
  val triples = for {
    first <- Num.values
    second <- Num.values
    third <- Num.values
    if (first != second)
    if (first != third)
    if (second != third)
  } yield Set(first, second, third)
}
```

I get an error on the line with third.  It says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - not enough arguments for method map: (implicit bf: 
         scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[sudoku.Triple.Num.ValueSet,scala.collection.immutable.Se    t[sudoku.Triple.Num.Value],That])That. Unspecified 
 value parameter bf.
- diverging implicit expansion for type 
 scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[sudoku.Triple.Num.ValueSet,scala.collection.immutable.Set[sudoku.Triple.Num.Value],That] starting with 
 method newCanBuildFrom in object SortedSet
- not enough arguments for method map: (implicit bf: 
 scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[sudoku.Triple.Num.ValueSet,scala.collection.immutable.Set[sudoku.Triple.Num.Value],That])That. Unspecified 
 value parameter bf.
- diverging implicit expansion for type 
 scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[sudoku.Triple.Num.ValueSet,scala.collection.immutable.Set[sudoku.Triple.Num.Value],That] starting with 
 method newCanBuildFrom in object SortedSet
```

Update:  Aleksey Izmailov gave a great answer.  A slightly better implementation of the function is val triples=Num.values.subset(3).toSet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883906/what-is-a-diverging-implicit-expansion-error

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10938239/2684760

Comment: @ForNeVeR - I actually found the issue linked from that question more useful: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5534

Comment: This issue is not resolved, but behavior changed already in some cases between 2.10 and 2.11. Maybe there is another related issue that caused regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like what you are trying to do is this:

```
scala> object Num extends Enumeration {
     |     type Num = Value
     |     val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
     |   }
defined module Num

scala>   val triples = Num.values.toList.combinations(3)
triples: Iterator[List[Num.Value]] = non-empty iterator

scala> triples.toList
res0: List[List[Num.Value]] = List(List(one, two, three), List(one, two, four), List(one, two, five), List(one, two, six), List(one, two, seven), List(one, two, eight), List(one, two, nine), List(one, three, four), List(one, three, five), List(one, three, six), List(one, three, seven), List(one, three, eight), List(one, three, nine), List(one, four, five), List(one, four, six), List(one, four, seven), List(one, four, eight), List(one, four, nine), List(one, five, six), List(one, five, seven), List(one, five, eight), List(one, five, nine), List(one, six, seven), List(one, six, eight), List(one, six, nine), List(one, seven, eight), List(one, seven, nine), List(one, eight, nine), List(two, three, four), List(two, three, five), List(two, three, six), List(two, three, seven), List(two, three...
scala>
```

If you do something like this then it works:

```
scala> object Triple {
     |   object Num extends Enumeration {
     |     type Num = Value
     |     val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
     |   }
     |   val triples = for {
     |     first <- Num.values
     |     second <- Num.values
     |     third <- Num.values
     |     if (first != second)
     |     if (first != third)
     |     if (second != third)
     |   } yield (first, second, third)
     | }
defined module Triple

scala> Triple.triples
res1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[(Triple.Num.Value, Triple.Num.Value, Triple.Num.Value)] = TreeSet((one,two,three), (one,two,four), (one,two,five), (one,two,six), (one,two,seven), (one,two,eight), (one,two,nine), (one,three,two), (one,three,four), (one,three,five), (one,three,six), (one,three,seven), (one,three,eight), (one,three,nine), (one,four,two), (one,four,three), (one,four,five), (one,four,six), (one,four,seven), (one,four,eight), (one,four,nine), (one,five,two), (one,five,three), (one,five,four), (one,five,six), (one,five,seven), (one,five,eight), (one,five,nine), (one,six,two), (one,six,three), (one,six,four), (one,six,five), (one,six,seven), (one,six,eight), (one,six,nine), (one,seven,two), (one,seven,three), (one,seven,four), (one,seven,five), (one,seven,six), (one,...
scala>
```

Note the result of the produced collection is a `SortedSet`. That result is defined by `Num.values` - you can convert `for` comprehension to `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` to check how the types come about.

The problem is that you can put stuff that can be sorted into `SortedSet` like this for example:

```
scala> scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet(1, 2)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2)
```

However, you can't put something that does not have ordering defined into a `SortedSet` because `SortedSet` guarantees that the stuff is sorted and should know how sorting is done (via implicit ordering):

```
scala> scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet(Set(1, 2), Set(3, 4))
<console>:8: error: No implicit Ordering defined for scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int].
              scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet(Set(1, 2), Set(3, 4))
```

Scala looks for implicit `Ordering` to be defined in scope and does not find one for the `Set` that you are using, or for the `Set[Int]` in my example.

Now let's "fix" it:

```
scala> implicit val dummyOrdering: Ordering[Set[Int]] = Ordering.by(_.size)
dummyOrdering: Ordering[Set[Int]] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@6f00d9a7

scala> scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet(Set(1, 2), Set(3, 4))
res8: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = TreeSet(Set(3, 4))
```

Obviously, this is a bad fix and the real problem is that in your case types are not well chosen. First of all you don't need to use a `Set` for each combination since you already comparing things to avoid repetition. Just use a `Tuple3`. Second, if you insist on using a `Set`, then convert `Num.values` to `List` in the `for` comprehension:

```
scala> object Triple {
     |   object Num extends Enumeration {
     |     type Num = Value
     |     val one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = Value
     |   }
     |   val triples = for {
     |     first <- Num.values.toList
     |     second <- Num.values.toList
     |     third <- Num.values.toList
     |     if (first != second)
     |     if (first != third)
     |     if (second != third)
     |   } yield Set(first, second, third)
     | }
defined module Triple
```

Hope that makes it clear. Basically the problem is in the choice of wrong types.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2.11. Still, this is a good description of how it _should_ work.

Comment: which part doesn't work in 2.11 @wingedsubmariner? I tried it in 2.10.3 REPL.

Comment: Replacing `Set(first, second, third)` with `(first, second, third)` doesn't change the error produced in 2.11. I can confirm that it does eliminate the error in 2.10.3.

Comment: Very interesting. It must be a regression. strange... :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  It looks like my error was writing "Set(first,second,third)" instead of "(first,second,third".  I don't really understand why that was an error though.  I also don't understand why that wouldn't return a list.